# update logged to 1 in mysql using php

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am just trying to get php to update logged on an account when they successfully log in.  I just cannot seem to get this one line to work (everything else is).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` WHERE `Username`='".$username."' SET `logged`='1'");
```

This is a login system I have made in unity.

Thanks,

Doomie

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
UPDATE accounts
SET logged = 1
WHERE Username = '$username'
```

The `SET` clause must be before the `WHERE` clause.